# How do I make a flexbox container surround absolutely-positioned content?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm working on a website where I'd like to have a slideshow on the left, and some text describing the slides on the right. Currently, I'm using flexbox and some absolute-positioned images for the slideshow. I'm also using a div around my content to provide a frame. However, the div does not wrap around the full height of the element, making the image overflow the frame. Is it possible to have the div completely wrap around the slideshow images while only providing a max- and min-width in the CSS?

Here's what I have currently:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="slides">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2048x1365">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/2048x1365">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>This is some content.</p>
        <p>This is some more content.</p>
        <p>This is some more content.</p>
        <p>This is some more content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 30px;
}
.content {
    background: red;
    flex: auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 30em;
    max-width: 38em;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px;
}
.slides {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vuz9wzx5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `position: absolute` of the image messes up the layout as it yanks it out of the element flow and so you cannot leverage flexbox the way you want.
I would:

- either only show on image programmatically
- show only the first image using CSS

I made some changes and a proposal for option two:
http://jsfiddle.net/vuz9wzx5/2/

**Update**

If you need absolute positioning for the image, you need to fix the height of the image container as in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vuz9wzx5/3/

Comment: I see. I think I'm stuck using absolute positioning as I want the images to fade into each other using a CSS animation (not included in the original post)? Also, I don't see any changes made in the fiddle?

Comment: I made some optimizations for the image, I gave it `min-width: 100%` and removed `height: auto` as it is not required. Also I updated the answer with another proposal.